# NIntegrate and MaxRecursion

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

I'm using `NIntegrate` to get the value of a very complicated function `f[k,T,M]`, where `T` and `M` are some parameters:

```
S[T_, M_, MaxRec_]:= NIntegrate[f[k, T, M], {k,0,Infinity}, PrecisionGoal->10, MaxRecursion->MaxRec]
```

What puzzles me is the fact that, for the same parameters, I get different values depending on `MaxRec` (with messages `NIntegrate::slwcon`, `NIntegrate::ncvb`):

```
S[10^12, 10^12, 10]
```

[image]
[image]

```
1.30494*10^30
```

*versus* (with only the message `NIntegrate::slwcon`)

```
S[10^12, 10^12, 50]
```

[image]

```
-1.161*10^45
```

How should I interpret these results? I could provide the explicit form of `f` if needed. Thanks a lot!

**EDITED**

I tried to increase `MaxRec=200` and I got the same warning message and the same value: `S[10^12, 10^12, 200]=-1.161*10^45`.

Here is the explicit form of the function `f`. I'm aware the expressions are ugly, so I apologize in advance.

```
gw = 2;

I0[y0_, y_] := Log[(Exp[y0 + y] - 1)/(Exp[y0 - y] - 1)] - y
I1[y0_, y_] := 
 1/2 (y0 + y) Log[(1 + Exp[(y0 + y)/2])/(1 - Exp[(-y0 + y)/2])] - 
  1/2 (y0 - y) Log[(1 + Exp[(y0 - y)/2])/(1 - Exp[(-y0 - y)/2])] + 
  PolyLog[2, -Exp[(y0 + y)/2]] + PolyLog[2, Exp[(-y0 - y)/2]] - 
  PolyLog[2, -Exp[(y0 - y)/2]] - PolyLog[2, Exp[(-y0 + y)/2]]

Sigma0[k0_, k_, T_, M_] := (gw T^2)/(8 \[Pi] k) I1[k0/T, k/T]
Sigmai[k0_, k_, T_, M_] := (gw T^2)/(8 \[Pi] k^3) (k0 I1[k0/T, k/T] - M^2/(2 T) I0[k0/T, k/T])

K0[k_, M_] := Sqrt[k^2 + M^2]

Sigma2[k_, T_, M_] := Sigma0[K0[k, M], k, T, M]^2 - k^2 Sigmai[K0[k, M], k, T, M]^2

feq[k_, T_, M_] := 1/(Exp[K0[k, M]/T] + 1)

f[k_, T_, M_] :=  -feq[k, T, M] k^2/K0[k, M] Sigma2[k, T, M]/gw
```

Comment: "Failed to converge" indicates an unreliable result (with a report of the estimated unreliability).  "Slow convergence" is a diagnostic hint, to help you figure out how to address a serious problem if one should occur.  What to do depends on `f`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @Michael-E2. I guess a follow up question would be if my second result is still unreliable (and, consequently, I need to keep increasing  `MaxRec`) or if I can trust it.

Comment: If you give an explicit form for your function, you may get useful advice. All I can say otherwise is not to trust the results, unless you have strong evidence that they are correct.

Comment: For a nice enough function — no (weak) singularities, finite number of oscillations, after transformation to a finite interval — one expects convergence like this from the global adaptive strategy: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnCmn.png. There are three regimes one may observe, pre-convergent, convergent, and converged. They may be arbitrarily long. Singularities and oscillatory behavior interfere with this convergence picture. Your result reports an estimated precision of just 1 digit. I wouldn't trust it.

Comment: @mikado I have added the explicit expression for `f`, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelE2, How do you know the estimated precision is just 1 digit? What would you recommend to get a reliable result? Thanks!

Comment: The value and error estimate are given in the error message.  In the pre-convergent phase, the error estimate can be inaccurate, but it's usually not small.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelE2! If I got the same result after setting `MaxRec=200`, should I trust the result now?